# Modify HTML file in a c sharp class

Tags: c#, html

First of all my application is not a web application. 
My aim is reading html files and modify them.

So that I write this code:

```
    string fileName = "~\\ActivationMail.html";
    string textLine = string.Empty;

    System.IO.StreamReader objReader;
    objReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);

    do
    {
        textLine += objReader.ReadLine();
        if (textLine.Contains("id=\"link\""))
        {
            textLine += "href=\"www.google.com\"";
        }
    } while (objReader.Peek() != -1);

    objReader.Close();
```

But each time reading whole html file is not seems to best solution. Can I change specific divs without reading(looping) whole html file? Is it possible?

Comment: I think you'd find the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples) helpful

Comment: I was about to suggest HAP as well. Just saw it in another SO post and remembered this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are wanting to just change certain things, you could be able to do this with XPath. Using the HTML Agility Pack, you can do this using C#.

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can load the HTML as XML using XElement etc, but ultimately if you are removing or inserting characters you will need to resize the file and relocate the characters.

Comment: HTML is not so strict as XML (e.g unclosed tags, etc), so it's possible that XElement could not load invalid HTML file

Answer (score 0):

Install the HAP package:

```
Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack -Version 1.11.27
```

String:

```
// From String
string result ="<div id="RemoveableDiv"></div> <div id="2"></div>"
```

Code:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(result);
foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode
.Descendants("div")
.Where(d => d.GetAttributeValue("Id", "RemoveableDiv").IndexOf("NavContent") >= 0)
.ToArray())
node.Remove();

result = doc.documentnode.innerhtml;
```

Answer (score 0):

Get position of start and end index of section_1

```
stringIndex =StringNthOccFinder.IndexOfNth(HtmlSting, "<Section_1", 0, 1);
endIdex = StringNthOccFinder.IndexOfNth(HtmlSting, "</Section_1>", 0, 14);
```

get HTML section which you want to remove

```
  HtmlSection= result.Substring(stringIndex , endIdex - stringIndex );
```

Replace html section to ""

```
   result = result.Replace(HtmlSection, "");
```